# Loop with continues processing

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application i have While(True) { } loop which are continuously running. 
This take 100% CPU usage.
Even this while loop is called from multiple thread to run some specific function so it is forcing CPU to run at its 100%.

I have placed some sleep according to some condition Like collection is Empty then need to sleep but in case collection is full then it is not reducing the usage of CPU.

```
While(true)
{
if(condition)
Thread.sleep(30);//Under some condition
//Process data on collection
//Set sleep condition
}
```

How can i control this loop and allow other process and thread to work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put sleep after the if :

```
while(true) 
{
   if (condition) {
      //treat data
   }
   sleep(30)
}
```

For now you are only sleeping when the list is empty, when it's full you're back to active wait, hence the 100% CPU